# Play video tag audio only through WebAudio node

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Suppose I have a page with a video tag in it. I can connect the audio output of that video to a WebaAudio node like this:

```
const source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(video);
source.connect(myNode);
```

Then I can take that node and connect it to `audioContext.destination` to hear the result. The problem is that I also seem to hear the output of the original video, before it gets processed by my audio node. I want to basically channel the video output *exclusively* through my node. How can I do this?

Note that I want to leave the audio controls on the video element alone, that is, I can't use a solution involving `video.muted = true` or something, since the user will see the volume meter at zero in the UI, which I don't want. I want to let the user set the video volume with the controls, then take the output of that and pipe it into my audio node.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a Firefox bug, or more specifically a bug in the Ubuntu package build of Firefox.

Ubuntu Firefox package issue page: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1852645